# Google signin play services android

Tags: android, service, google-play-services

I have android application, that I want to enchant some multiplayer like features, limited to leaderboard. I would like to use google play services to manage that. The problem is that as I see it, first of all I'll need to implement google sign-in process inside my application, then I'll have to impelement google play services. Unfortunately, I'm still doing my first steps into android, thus, searching all over the internet for paid and free content, but couldn't find a tutorial that explains this procedure. Google developer documentation is great, but hard for me to follow at the moment due to lack of understanding.

I was wondering, maybe someone faced something of this kind, and could direct me where should I start and where to finish, some algorithm, what goes first. Or maybe a tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for google signin refer this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, could you suggest what should i do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Google Sign in to implement in your Android code, then the Google Docs can help you with that. It will provide you some sample code that you can copy to achieve this. It also explain you the step by step procedure that you need to follow.
So check this [Implementing Sign-in in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) and [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

If you want some tutorials, then check this link:

- [Android Login with Google Tutorial](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/adding-google-login-android-app/)
- [Android Login with Google Plus Account](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)